# Check input of setter in C# arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, setter

I made a class "Kleurencombinatie" and in that class there is array with a get and set.

```
byte[] combinatie;
public byte[] Combinatie
{
    get { return combinatie; }
    set { combinatie = value; } 
}
```

I can chance the values of the array by doing

```
Kleurencombinatie Combo = new Kleurencombinatie();
Combo.Combinatie[0]++;
```

But the problem is that it creates an overflow. So my idea was to validate the input of the setter. I can simply do that with Modulo(%). But I dont know how you would do this in the setter.

Example how I wanted it to be:

```
byte aantalkleuren;
public byte Aantalkleuren
{
    get { return aantalkleuren; }
    set { aantalkleuren = value % 7; }
    //The max value of is 6 now. As soon it over 6 its starts again at 0
}
```

A solution would be, making a function for this. But I think it is possible to do this in the setter itself.

Any ideas how?
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of overflow does it make ? Memory or Stack ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I've updated your post to include the code in the question - there's no need to use a pastebin type service. Just use the curly brackets to turn text to code.

Comment: @Tigran I think they mean a numeric overflow.

Comment: What is wrong with the example setter you posted. Are you getting any errors? If so, what?

Comment: Do you want to constrain the index used to reference the array, or do you want to constrain the values of the bytes in the array?

Comment: @Tigran The overflow is caused by something else. But that doesnt matter.

I just want to make sure the array values dont go over a specified number.

Answer (score 3):

If you expose a raw array through a property like that, you cannot intercept the writes to its elements in order to validate the values.

However, you could instead write your own class that implements an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public sealed class RangeCheckedByteArray
{
    public RangeCheckedByteArray(int size)
    {
        _data = new byte[size];
    }

    public byte this[int index] // This indexer ensures that values are checked.
    {
        get
        {
            return _data[index];
        }

        set // Nobody can set an element's value without coming through here.
        {
            _data[index] = (byte)(value%7);
        }
    }

    private readonly byte[] _data;
}
```

Use that in place of the byte array, and it will do what you need:

```
RangeCheckedByteArray combinatie;
public RangeCheckedByteArray Combinatie
{
    get { return combinatie; }
    set { combinatie = value; } 
}
```

Comment: Ke thanks!
This looks good but I will probably make a function in my class instead of making an extra class just for this.

Comment: C# does not charge by the class :) If a behavior is best encapsulated with within a class, do no hesitate to extract that logic.

Answer (score 1):

If the code shown is all the code for the array, it will fail with a `NullReferenceException`, because the array will not be created yet, just declared. You still need to initialize it, e.g. in the constructor of the class, or in the calling code

```
Kleurencombinatie Combo = new Kleurencombinatie();
Combo.Combinatie = new byte[length];
Combo.Combinatie[0]++;
```

Also, the setter and the getter are for the **byte array** itself, not for the individual elements. Those can still be accessed and set to any valid value, just as in any other `byte[]`

Comment: Well I didn't gave you the whole code. But this was done in the constructor of the class.